# Program crashes when sending TCP packet

Tags: java, android, tcp

This is my first app on android and I'm trying to write a TCP client.

So far, I have a python TCP server and I tested it with python TCP client and it works fine.

I took the TCP client example from [here](https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/20/android-tcp-connection-tutorial/#.Wd4IrGgjSUk).

When I start the app, I can see on wireshark the handshake so the connection was established.

Now, the problem is with sending message. when I put the function call

```
if (mTcpClient != null) 
{
   mTcpClient.sendMessage("testing");
}
```

in the main activity:

```
public void ChangeButtonState(View view) 
{
    boolean state = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if (state) 
     {

        if (mTcpClient != null) {
            mTcpClient.sendMessage("testing");
        }


        textView.setText("button is on. sent Tcp message. ");
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        textView.setText("button is off");
    }
}
```

The code crashes on the line `mBufferOut.println(message);` in TcpClient class.

But if I call that function right after the line `mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());` in TcpClient class, the client transmit the message, the server receives it and sends it back to client.

So my question is why is the code crashing? the `mTcpClient` member is not null.

Comment: Are you running this code from Main thread? Please share stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send network requests in a background thread. Use `AsyncTask` or `Thread`.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        mTcpClient.sendMessage("test");
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Thanks! solved the problem. why should it be on thread anyway?

Comment: Glad I could help. If you send network requests in the foreground thread, the app will freeze till the request is completed. So the android SDK has forced the developers to perform network calls in a background thread.